# How to be notified when, and which, RecyclerView item has been Snapped into place by SnapHelper?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I set up my recyclerView with a SnapHelper in the standard way.  That works fine.  However, I need to be notified when an item has been "snapped" into place so that I can update a TextView with that index.  I've tried setting setOnFlingListener on the recyclerView, but snapHelper has already set an instance of it so an exception is thrown.

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new PlantAdapter(this, Globals.getPlants());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    snapHelper = new snapHelper(this);
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Is there another way to know exactly when, and which, item has been snapped?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out.  I added an onScrollListener to the recyclerview, then get the position in onScrollStateChanged when the scroll state is SCROLL_STATE_IDLE.

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if(newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                View centerView = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager);
                if (centerView != null) {
                    int pos = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
                    updateAdapterPosition(pos);
                }
                else {
                    updateAdapterPosition(markers.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```